# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'int' *args even number list

Tags: python, int, tuples

## Returns a list that contain arguments even

```
def myfunc(*args):
    blist = []
    args = ()
    if args%2 == 0:
        print(blist.append(args))
    else:
        print("Not even")
myfunc(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

Comment: `if len(args)%2 == 0:` but that will always be the case, given that you set it to `()`.

Comment: You aren't iterating over the tuple `args`; you are treating it as a single `int`.

Comment: (In fact, you are overwriting whatever arguments may have been passed with `args = ()`.)

Comment: do you want to print out arguments that are even or the length of the arguments are even or not

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate over the given arguments, testing each in turn.

```
def myfunc(*args):
    blist = []
    for arg in args:
        if arg % 2 == 0:
            blist.append(arg)
        else:
            print("Not even")
    return blist
```

Once the loop is complete, you also have to return the list you just built. Printing the return value of `blist.append` doesn't provide any interesting information; it wold just print `None`, not the value you just added to the list.